# Stop Firefox displaying Chinese in Yahoo Mail

Tags: firefox, language, yahoo-mail, firefox-profile

Yahoo Mail is displaying Chinese (or other?) language characters on the webmail view. I tried to eliminate it by disabling all Add-ons disabled, but it still came up the same.

I found that deleting the Firefox file prefs.js corrects the problem (But it also deletes all my settings).

The prefs.js can be edited through the url address about:config, but I don't know which setting is the problem. I tried searching "yahoo" and "language", but nothing useful came up. I could go through and test reset each config to default 1 by 1, but that would take me quite a while.

I need to find out which pref.js key/value pair is making Yahoo Mail display Asian characters.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a tab and type in the address `about:config`. Find this key name

```
browser.display.use_document_fonts
```

Reset it's value, or set to `1`.